# change text of tableviews delete button titanium

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

how can I change the text of the red delete button of a tableview?

this is my tableview:

```
    var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        editable : true,
        backgroundColor : 'transparent',
        separatorColor : 'transparent',
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    });
```

then i have the event listener for the 'DELET' event. but i need to change the text of the button from 'DELET' to 'X'

how can i du that?

I'm not using the alloy folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `deleteButtonTitle` property of the `TableView` :  http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow-property-deleteButtonTitle